# Explain this jQuery effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please can some explain what is happening in this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var $scrollingDiv = $(".floatdetails");
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
            maxY = $('#foot').offset().top,
            scrollHeight = $scrollingDiv.height()
            if (y < maxY - scrollHeight - 375) {
                $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({
                    "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I need to do is to not let margin-top be less than 0. You can [see here](http://holybay.tk/Lab/page.html) why I need that. And also not let .floatdetails to cross the footer.

And obviously you can guess that I am a jQuery beginner. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which sectin is unclear for u?

Comment: $(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
    maxY = $('#foot').offset().top,

Comment: I have posted explanation as comment in answer. Is this clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the explanation in comment

```
//Function will be triggered on scrolling 
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //How much height is scrolled is assigned to y;
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
            //top position of the $('#foot') is assigned to maxY
            maxY = $('#foot').offset().top,
            //height of $(".floatdetails") is assigned to scrollHeight
            scrollHeight = $scrollingDiv.height()
    if (y < maxY - scrollHeight - 375) {
        //Base od the condition $(".floatdetails") is animated
        $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({
            "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```